# What are the differences between Java's dir.listFiles() and *.nix's ls?

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix

I've written some java code that gets the number of files in a directory using `dir.listFiles().length;`. The command `ls -l | wc` gives me a different number. I believe that both of the commands skip hidden directories. What could be the cause for the differing numbers?

Comment: Just to know, which one was right?

Comment: Well, this directory has over almost 2000 files so, I can't be sure. With directories containing less files, the programs seem to report proper totals.

Comment: The difference is that `ls -l` returns an extra row (which says something like: `Total: #####`)

Comment: Thanks Barranka. Using `ls` still returns differing numbers.

Comment: if u used `ls -l | wc -l` , there would've been no difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l | wc
```

that counts number of line that `ls -l` outputs, in a directory with single file it will still output 2 lines that doesn't mean it has 2 files inside that directory

Comment: Thanks Jigar. Using just ls still returns differing numbers. Additionally, I created a dir with one file and `ls|wc` reports  `1       1       4`

Answer (score 0):

From `man wc` :

```
 wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file.
```

When command  `ls -l | wc` gives output something like `3   7   15` , `wc` tells that there are 3 newlines, 7 words and 15 characters(bytes) in the input ( the output of `ls -l` ). The 3 newlines means there are 3 files since `ls -l` lists each file with a newline.

On the other hand `dir.listFiles().length` in Java is the length of the `File` array returned by `dir.listFiles()` method which is indeed the number of files in the `dir`.

If you want similar results from `wc`, pass the `-lines` or simply `-l` option which prints only the newline count :

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

**Most importantly**, the `dir.listFiles()` will list all in the `dir` including **hidden files** which `ls` **doesn't list by default**. To be consistent with result from Java, use :

```
  ls -la | wc -l
```